# OpenSSL BN_CTX usage

Tags: openssl, bignum

From [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BN_CTX_new.html) I understand that `BN_CTX` is a structure that holds `BIGNUM` temporary variables. When will those `BIGNUM` variables enter `BN_CTX`'s `BN_POOL`? If I have a bignum_ctx `BN_CTX *ctx` (either declared at the top of my function, or passed in as an argument), when should I do

```
ctx = BN_CTX_new();
/* Do something */
BN_CTX_free(ctx);
```

and when should I do the following instead?

```
BN_CTX_start(ctx);
/* Do something */
BN_CTX_end(ctx);
```

And if I have a bignum `BIGNUM *bn`, in what circumstances should I use

```
BN_CTX_start(ctx);
bn = BN_CTX_get(ctx);
BN_CTX_end(ctx);
```

instead of just new and free the instance?

```
bn = BN_new();
if (bn)
    BN_free(bn);
```

Answer (score 26):

Here I am answering my own question. I guess it happens all the time in SO.

BIGNUM in OpenSSL is a complicated structure that holds an arbitrarily big number, and hence creating and freeing BIGNUM instances repeatedly will result in a considerable overhead. BIGNUM context, or BN_CTX, is created and used to save this overhead.

**Structure**

The BN_CTX structure contains two structures: `BN_POOL` and `BN_STACK`. The `BN_POOL` keeps a bundle of temporary bignums with a linked-list, while the `BN_STACK` manages the stack frame.

**On Create**

A `BN_CTX` instance `ctx` is created with `BN_CTX_new()`. A function must call `BN_CTX_start()` to get a new stack frame first. By calling `BN_CTX_get(ctx)`, OpenSSL looks for an unused bignum in the `BN_POOL` of `ctx`. If there isn't any available temp bignum, OpenSSL will create one and link to the linked-list. This must be done before passing `ctx` as argument to other functions.

Of course there's a mechanism for preventing user creating too many temporary bignums. The predefined number of bignums you can create within a `BN_POOL` is 16. Once the limit is exceeded, probable segmentation fault will occur at random location in OpenSSL library.

**On Exit**

After the function is done with the BIGNUM instance it got from `ctx` and is ready to exit,  `BN_CTX_end()` is called to release temporary bignums, meaning that these bignums become "unused" and can be requested by the next `BN_CTX_get()`.

Finally, probably after several times of `BN_CTX_start()` and `BN_CTX_end()`, `BN_CTX_end()` is called to free `BN_STACK` structure, and clear free bignums in `BN_POOL`.

**Example Code**

```
void foo(){
    BN_CTX* ctx;
    ctx = BN_CTX_new();

    /* Using BIGNUM context in a series of BIGNUM operations */
    bar(ctx);
    bar(ctx);
    bar(ctx);

    /* Using BIGNUM context in a function called in loops */
    while(/*condition*/){
        bar(ctx);
    }

    BN_CTX_free(ctx);
}
```

And here's the function `bar( )`

```
void bar(BN_CTX* ctx){
    BIGNUM *bn;
    BN_CTX_start(ctx);
    bn = BN_CTX_get(ctx);

    /* Do something with bn */

    BN_CTX_end(ctx);
}
```

The function `foo()` creates a new BIGNUM context and pass it as argument to function `bar()`. Upon the first time `bar()` calls `BN_CTX_get()`, a temporary bignum is created and stored in the `BN_POOL` and is returned. `BN_CTX_get()` in the subsequent `bar()` will not create new bignum but instead returns the one it created in the first place. This temporary bignum will finally be clear-freed by `BN_CTX_free()` in `foo()`.

**Conclusion**

When performance is in concern, use `BN_CTX` to save the overhead of BIGNUM creation by passing it to functions that

1. require BIGNUM structures to hold temporary big numbers, and
2. are called sequentially to perform certain bignum operations, or
3. are repeatedly called in loops.

Be aware that there is a limitation for the number of bignums stored in `BN_CTX`. If performance is not an issue, then using

```
bn = BN_new();
if (bn)
    BN_free(bn);
```

is just fine.

Comment: What's the stack frame for?

Comment: Since a BN_CTX object `ctx` can be pass from functions to functions, stack frame is a bunch of information used to track the depth of these function calls(which pass `ctx` as argument), and the size of the memory allocated to `ctx`.

Comment: I guess it is for releasing tmp variables function by function. If there is a function uses two tmp BIGNUMs `bn1 = BN_CTX_get(ctx); bn2 = BN_CTX_get(ctx);` There is no way (to me) to release `bn1` but not `bn2`. They can only be released together on BN_CTX_end. The stack frame information is to remember this function is using two tmps `bn1` and `bn2`, I guess.

Comment: I think you're right. Stack frame keeps the number of bignums assigned to this ctx.